# Maple 17: Why doesn't series(...,n) always return a series expansion of order n?

Tags: maple

In the following example, why does the first `series(f,n=infinity,9);` return a series of order 8, but it returns a series of order 9 only after executing `series(f,n=infinity,10);`?

```
    |\^/|     Maple 17 (X86 64 LINUX)
._|\|   |/|_. Copyright (c) Maplesoft, a division of Waterloo Maple Inc. 2013
 \  MAPLE  /  All rights reserved. Maple is a trademark of
   Waterloo Maple Inc.
      |       Type ? for help.
> f := 1 + (n-1)*6/n^3 - (1+6/n^3)^(n-2) * (1+6/n^3/(1+(n^2/2)*6/n^3));
                    6 (n - 1)   /     6  \(n - 2) /         6      \
           f := 1 + --------- - |1 + ----|        |1 + ------------|
                        3       |      3 |        |     3          |
                       n        \     n  /        \    n  (1 + 3/n)/

> series(f,n=infinity,8);
                              198   810      1
                              --- - --- + O(----)
                               6     7        8
                              n     n        n

> series(f,n=infinity,9);
                              198   810      1
                              --- - --- + O(----)
                               6     7        8
                              n     n        n

> series(f,n=infinity,10);
                       198   810   2952   11070      1
                       --- - --- + ---- - ----- + O(---)
                        6     7      8      9        10
                       n     n      n      n        n

> series(f,n=infinity,9);
                          198   810   2952      1
                          --- - --- + ---- + O(----)
                           6     7      8        9
                          n     n      n        n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third paragraph in the Description section of the help-page for the series command mentions that the `order` parameter specifies the truncation order for the calculation and is not necessarily the order of the returned series.

Also, there is a remember table in play, so that a higher order returned result may be quickly truncated when a subsequent lower truncation order query is computed. (The `Order` environment variable is being treated somewhat analogously to the `Digits` environment variable, in that better or more accurate saved results might be truncated/rounded quickly when a coarser query is made.)

After requesting clearance of a remember table for `series`, the lower order query must once more be actually computed (using the specified truncation order of the calculation) rather than merely looked up and truncated.

```
restart:
kernelopts(version);

      Maple 17.02, X86 64 WINDOWS, Sep 5 2013, Build ID 872941

f := 1 + (n-1)*6/n^3 - (1+6/n^3)^(n-2) * (1+6/n^3/(1+(n^2/2)*6/n^3)):

series(f,n=infinity,9);

                          198   810    /1 \
                          --- - --- + O|--|
                           6     7     | 8|
                          n     n      \n /

series(f,n=infinity,10);

                  198   810   2952   11070    / 1 \
                  --- - --- + ---- - ----- + O|---|
                   6     7      8      9      | 10|
                  n     n      n      n       \n  /

series(f,n=infinity,9);

                      198   810   2952    /1 \
                      --- - --- + ---- + O|--|
                       6     7      8     | 9|
                      n     n      n      \n /

forget(series);

series(f,n=infinity,9);

                          198   810    /1 \
                          --- - --- + O|--|
                           6     7     | 8|
                          n     n      \n /
```

Comment: Indeed, though the `order` parameter is documented as being the order used in the (internal) computations, the fact that there is a remember table in play is not documented at all, and this is what confused me (together with the fact that the output order on this example is not linear: 8 gives 8, 9 gives 8 too initially, 10 gives 10). I sent a remark on http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Order and got the same answer. I hope that the help will be improved in the future.